# How do you create a nested book within bookdown?

Tags: github, yaml, r-markdown, github-pages, bookdown

Within the navigation, bookdown only allows for 3 levels of headings.  I am trying to create a book with at least 8 levels.  It is very important for even the 8th level to be easily navigated to.  I was thinking about solving this solution with a nested book.  For example, you have your first book.  Then within a page in your first book, you have a link that you click on, that takes you to your second book.

The issue is, since I am creating two books, I would have two index.Rmd files - which doesn't work, since both would be located in same location on github.  It would also mean my website would have the same webaddress for two pages.  Another issue is, I don't think that when searching in the first book, pages in the second book will show up.

What are some ways to solve the problem of needing more than 3 levels in navigation?  Currently I was thinking about nested books but am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

More than three levels of headings [are possible](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-with-more-than-3-levels-in-navigation/80830/6?u=jtbayly). Simply put the following in your YAML.

```
gitbook:
    toc_depth: 6
```

However, that doesn't get you to 8, since there are only 6 levels of headers in HTML, I believe.

You could [use PART](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#special-headers) to get to 7. Not sure how you'd get to 8, except by splitting into multiple books.